# CacheManager.getCacheFileBaseDir() always returns null

Tags: android, caching, httpwebrequest

I've been trying to use the [CacheManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CacheManager.html) for caching some http
requests but it failed every time with a nullpointer exception. After
some digging I believe I found out why:

`CacheManager.getCacheFileBaseDir()` always returns null so when I try
to use `CacheManager.getCacheFile()` or `CacheManager.saveCacheFile()`
they fail.

`CacheManager.cacheDisabled()` returns false.

I hadn 't created a cache partition via the AVD manager so I thought
the problem lie there. But after creating a cache partition
`getCacheFile()` still return null:

```
03-16 00:25:16.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 00:25:16.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(296): at android.webkit.CacheManager.getCacheFile(CacheManager.java:296)
```

What could be the problem? I've got the code posted here:
http://pastebin.com/eaJwfXEK
But it's a bit messy because I've been trying tons of stuff.

Why does `CacheManager.getCacheFileBaseDir()` return null and not a File object?

Answer (score 1):

Could be related to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7222 : The CacheManager can only be used associated to a WebView. Bummer. I'll continue investigating.

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is a init(Context context)  method to call
but by viewing the source code, this method is not public
I can't call this method from my code.

I have always:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.CacheManager.getCacheFile(CacheManager.java:295)